# How do I force a chart to auto adjust Y Axis Maximum?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-charts

I have a .NET chart which I am populating at runtime

The chart appears within a report.  For each band in my report, I clear all the series and add them back in using code

```
            Series s = new Series();
            s.Font = new Font("Verdana", 8f);                

            int i = 0;
            foreach (var month in line.Months)
            {
                DataPoint p = new DataPoint();

                p.XValue = i;
                p.YValues = new Double[] { month.LineValue ?? 0 };
                s.Points.Add(p);

                i++;
            }
```

When I populate the chart the second time, the Y Axis maximum stays on 2000, i.e. is not being recalculated

How do I force recalculation?

I have ScaleBreakStyle enabled on the Y Axis

If I try to set IsLogarithmic to true on the Y Axis I get a X instead of a chart

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with the System.Windows.forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart

Paul

Comment: Looks like Anton Kedrov's answer should be the accepted solution

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();`

Comment: I also was trying to set `AxisY.Maximum = Double.NaN` (and same for AxisY2), but it's not working for me.

Comment: This answer worked for me. I was enabling/disabling different Series (all series are initially disabled and controlled from a list) and noticed that only the first Series enabled would set the maximum for the y-axis.

Answer (score 14):

[The docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.maximum.aspx) say the default for the `Axis.Maximum` property is NaN (not a number), so <strike>you should be able to re-enable the automatic scaling functionality by setting it back to that value</strike>.

Something like this...

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = Double.NaN;
```

**UPDATE / CORRECTION**

Anton's answer is correct; you should be using:

```
ChartArea.RecalculateAxesScale();
```

According to [the `RecalculateAxesScale()` docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.recalculateaxesscale(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ... it is sometimes
>   necessary to recalculate chart area properties so that the chart is
>   rendered correctly. For example, if an axis range is changed, the
>   labels for that axis must be recalculated.

Apparently, it's has been available since .NET 4.0.

Comment: I thought and tried the same thing but it didn't work. Anton Kedrov's answer works

Comment: @yclkvnc, can you post some version info? I think this solution once worked but it sounds like most people are having better luck with Anton's answer these days.

Comment: sorry, I don't even remember using .NET chart 5 years ago :)

Answer (score 7):

First, initialize this:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;
```

Whenever data point is added, do this please.

```
pinChart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
```

Comment: RecalculateAxesScale() is critical. IntervalOffset has no function on the axis.

Answer (score 6):

you need to run this sequence:

```
AxisY.Maximum = Double.NaN; // sets the Maximum to NaN
AxisY.Minimum = Double.NaN; // sets the Minimum to NaN
enter code herechart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale(); // recalculates the Maximum and Minimum values, since they are set to NaN
```