# Update y-axis maximum in chart

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

my English is not so good so I apologize in advance.
I tried something with the object `Chart` in a `WindowsFormsApplication`.
I built a program that looks like this:
[image]
And that is the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chart1.Series.Clear();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        chart1.Series.Add("button1 Series");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, i * 2);
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.Series.Clear();
        chart1.Series.Add("button2 Series");

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, i * 4);
    }
```

When I click the first button (`button1`), the graph is displayed as I want:
[image: button1]
But if after that I hit the second button (`button2`), points on the y-axis escape out:[image: button2]

The maximum of the y-axis (250) stay the same instead change to bigger.
How can I fix my program so that the graph will not get out of the area?
Thanks, and sorry again for my English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`ResetAutoValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.resetautovalues?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) method of the chart:

```
chart1.ResetAutoValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `chart.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale()` method successfully.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15227268/243572).